# How to get into GRUB on Presario CQ43 hp laptop to change root password without cd drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My laptop model: hp compaq Presario CQ43.
Operating system: win7
Dual boot: windows, Ubuntu..

Trying to get into Grub menu by pressing shift key with hold immediately after powering on laptop. Unable to get into grub.

Unable to work with second option to use Ubuntu cd as installation done without cd.

Is there any other alternative to get into grub without reinstalling Ubuntu to change root password?

Shyamal

Comment: Are you able to boot any of your two OS. Is it Grub menu getting skips and directly loading ubuntu ? mention your problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this is to use [SuperGRUB2Disk](http://supergrubdisk.org/) to look for Os's and list partitions etc.

You can mount it onto a USB it using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.net/)

Hope this helps